# How to explain Instruction replay in CUDA

Tags: cuda

Could anyone summarize the definition and reasons for different kinds of instruction replays in CUDA?

They are:

1. inst_replay_overhead:
2. shared_replay_overhead:
3. global_replay_overhead:
4. global_cache_replay_overhead
5. local_replay_overhead
6. atomic_replay_overhead
7. shared_load_replay
8. shared_store_replay
9. global_ld_mem_divergence_replays
10. global_st_mem_divergence_replays

Comment: It appears this is a request to provide some details about replay events reported by the CUDA profiler. The profiler basically reports the value of hardware counters (or ratios derived from them), which can be attached to various replay mechanism in the GPU hardware.I am not aware that NVIDIA has made any such micro-architectural details publicly available. More importantly, the hardware focus of the question in its current form makes it appear off-topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This answer applies to Compute Capability 2.0 - 3.7 (Fermi - Kepler) devices.

Each cycle each SM warp scheduler picks a warp and issues 1-2 independent instructions.

The event **inst_executed** is the count of warp instructions that complete. **thread_inst_executed** is the count of thread that complete an instruction.

If the SM is not able to complete the issued instruction due to

1. constant cache miss on immediate constant (constant referenced in the instruction),
2. address divergence in an indexed constant load,
3. address divergence in a global/local memory load or store,
4. bank conflict in a shared memory load or store,
5. address conflict in an atomic or reduction operation,
6. load or store operation require data to be written to the load store unit or read from a unit exceeding the read/write bus width (e.g. 128-bit load or store), or
7. load cache miss (replay occurs to fetch data when the data is ready in the cache)

then the SM scheduler has to issue the instruction multiple times. This is called an instruction replay. The value inst_issued == **inst_issued2** * 2 + **inst_issued1** is the number of instructions completed + instruction replays.

Instruction replays use an instruction issue slot reducing the compute throughput of the SM.

The ***_replay_overhead*** metrics listed below can help you identify which types of operations are causing replays. The **_replay** events can provide a magnitude.

**NVPROF/CUPTI EVENTS AND METRICS**

EVENT GROUP 1 - Generic instruction issue and retire count

- inst_executed:  Number of instructions executed, do not include replays.
- inst_issued1:  Number of single instruction issued per cycle
- inst_issued2:  Number of dual instructions issued per cycle
- inst_issued0:  Number of cycles that did not issue any instruction, increments per warp.

EVENT GROUP 2 - Count or replays for specific types of events listed above (not all events have counts)

- shared_load_replay: Replays caused due to shared load bank conflict (when the addresses for two or more shared memory load requests fall in the same memory bank) or when there is no conflict but the total number of words accessed by all thre
  ads in the warp executing that instruction exceed the number of words that can be loaded in one cycle (256 bytes).
- shared_store_replay:  Replays caused due to shared store bank conflict (when the addresses for two or more shared memory store requests fall in the same memory bank) or when there is no conflict but the total number of words accessed by all th
  reads in the warp executing that instruction exceed the number of words that can be stored in one cycle.
- global_ld_mem_divergence_replays:  Number of instruction replays for global memory loads. Instruction is replayed if the instruction is accessing more than one cache line of 128 bytes. For each extra cache line access the counter is incremented by 1.
- global_st_mem_divergence_replays:  Number of instruction replays for global memory stores. Instruction is replayed if the instruction is accessing more than one cache line of 128 bytes. For each extra cache line access the counter is incremented by 1.

METRIC GROUP - Calculation of efficiency.

- inst_replay_overhead:  Average number of replays for each instruction
  executed
- local_replay_overhead:  Average number of replays due to
  local memory accesses for each instruction executed
- atomic_replay_overhead:  Average number of replays due to atomic and
  reduction bank conflicts for each instruction executed
- global_replay_overhead:  Average number of replays due to global
  memory cache misses for each instruction executed
- shared_replay_overhead:  Average number of replays due to shared
  memory conflicts for each instruction executed
- global_cache_replay_overhead:  Average number of replays due to
  global memory cache misses for each instruction executed

**Compute Capability 5.x** devices (Maxwell) devices push replays from the warp scheduler to the individual units. This reduces replay latency and frees up the scheduler to issue math operations. The ratio of inst_issued / inst_executed = inst_replay_overhead will usually be close to 0 on these devices.

Comment: Thanks for you through explanation, could you explain the "load or store operation require data to be written to the load store unit or read from a unit exceeding the read/write bus width (e.g. 128-bit load or store), " a little bit more?