# Very large instruction replay overhead for random memory access on Kepler

Tags: cuda

I am studying the performance of random memory access on a Kepler GPU, K40m. The kernel I use is pretty simple as follows,

```
__global__ void scatter(int *in1, int *out1, int * loc, const size_t n) {

    int globalSize = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    int globalId = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    for (unsigned int i = globalId; i < n; i += globalSize) {
        int pos = loc[i];   
        out1[pos] = in1[i]; 
    }
}
```

That is, I will read an array in1 as well as a location array loc. Then I permute in1 according to loc and output to the array out1. Generally, out1[loc[i]] = in1[i]. Note that the location array is sufficiently shuffled and each element is unique.

And I just use the default nvcc compilation setting with -O3 flag opened. The L1 dcache is disabled. Also I fix my # blocks to be 8192 and block size of 1024.

I use nvprof to profile my program. It is easy to know that most of the instructions in the kernel should be memory access. For an instruction of a warp, since each thread demands a discrete 4 Byte data, the instruction should be replayed multiple times (at most 31 times?) and issue multiple memory transactions to fulfill the need of all the threads within the warp. However, the metric "inst_replay_overhead" seems to be confusing: when # tuples n = 16M, the replay overhead is 13.97, which makes sense to me. But when n = 600M, the replay overhead becomes 34.68. Even for larger data, say 700M and 800M, the replay overhead will reach 85.38 and 126.87.

The meaning of "inst_replay_overhead", according to document, is "Average number of replays for each instruction executed". Is that mean when n = 800M, on average each instruction executed has been replayed 127 times? How comes the replay time much larger than 31 here? Am I misunderstanding something or am I missing other factors that will also contribute greatly to the replay times? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding the fundamental meaning of an instruction replay.

`inst_replay_overhead` includes the number of times an instruction was issued, but wasn't able to be completed. This can occur for various reasons, which are explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35593124/939070). Pertinent excerpt from the answer:

> If the SM is not able to complete the issued instruction due to
>
> 1. constant cache miss on immediate constant (constant referenced in the instruction),
> 2. address divergence in an indexed constant load,
> 3. address divergence in a global/local memory load or store,
> 4. bank conflict in a
>      shared memory load or store,
> 5. address conflict in an atomic or
>      reduction operation,
> 6. load or store operation require data to be
>      written to the load store unit or read from a unit exceeding the
>      read/write bus width (e.g. 128-bit load or store), or
> 7. load cache miss
>      (replay occurs to fetch data when the data is ready in the cache)
>
> then
>   the SM scheduler has to issue the instruction multiple times. This is
>   called an instruction replay.

I'm guessing this happens because of scattered reads in your case. This concept of instruction replay also exists on the CPU side of things. Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_system).

Comment: As @ApporvaJ kindly pointed to my past answer a value of +63 is expected due to 31 way divergence and 32 miss grants. The rest are likely due to killed load or store requests. Each warp scheduler will try to submit a replay ever 4th cycle (round robin between the schedulers). If the pending request table or the write buffers are full then the replay is deferred and has to be re-issued. The profiler does not provide a breakdown of these issue reasons as they are not actionable.